# Javascript class extension

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, extend

**CONTEXT**

I have one Base class called `Entity` and `User` and `Group` are both derived from this object; If I instantiate a user with the `ID` of 12 for example, the next time I try to do that it returns the same object. I store these in a prototype `items` variable. To keep these `item` variables separate I have to declare the User And Group functions separately although they contain the same code.

**CODE**

```
Application.prototype.Entity = function() {

};

Application.prototype.Entity.prototype.print = function() {
    var container = $("<div class='user-tag'></div>");
    container.append("<a class='friend_list ellipsis_overflow' style='background-image:url(\"" + this.entity.pic.icon + "\");'"
        + "href ='user?id=" + this.entity.id + "'>" + this.entity.name + "</a>");

    return container;
};


//HOW TO GET RID OF THIS "REPETITION"
Application.prototype.User = function(entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
    this.entity.pic = this.entity.pic || Application.prototype.default.pic;
        if (this.items[this.entity.id]) {
        return this.items[this.entity.id];
    } else {
        this.items[this.entity.id] = this;
    }
};
Application.prototype.Group = function(entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
    this.entity.pic = this.entity.pic || Application.prototype.default.pic;
    if (this.items[this.entity.id]) {
        return this.items[this.entity.id];
    } else {
        this.items[this.entity.id] = this;
    }
};
// END REPEAT


Application.prototype.Group.prototype = new Application.prototype.Entity();
Application.prototype.User.prototype = new Application.prototype.Entity();

//Application.prototype.User.prototype.constructor = Application.prototype.Entity;
//Application.prototype.Group.prototype.constructor = Application.prototype.Entity; - these don't seem to work

//THESE items VARIABLES HAVE TO REMAIN SEPARATE
Application.prototype.Group.prototype.items = {};
Application.prototype.User.prototype.items = {};
```

**QUESTION**

I specifically would like to rid my code of the repetition mentioned above, but if you see any other unnecessary code, please comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function userAndGroupConstructor(entity) {
  this.entity = entity;
  this.entity.pic = this.entity.pic || Application.prototype.default.pic;
  if (this.items[this.entity.id]) {
    return this.items[this.entity.id];
  } else {
    this.items[this.entity.id] = this;
  }
}

Application.prototype.User = function() {
  return userAndGroupConstructor.apply(this, arguments)
}
Application.prototype.Group = function() {
  return userAndGroupConstructor.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

You get distinct constructors with distinct prototypes, but avoid duplication.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work as it is still combining the item variable.

Comment: @PatrickGeyer If the replacement is done, the code will be equivalent.    Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it. I'm not just trying to create identical functions

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Application.prototype.Group = Application.prototype.User;
```

Since `Application.prototype.User` contains the function reference, you can just assign it to `Application.prototype.Group`.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried this already but it still doesn't keep two separate item variables.